# How the states are chosen in this Tree Automaton Example

Tags: automata

I have a few basic questions about how the states work in Tree Automata.

> **[Example 1.1.2](http://tata.gforge.inria.fr/)**. Let $F = \{f(,),g(),a\}$. Consider the automaton $A = (Q, F, Q_f, \Delta)$
>   defined by: $Q = \{q,q_g,q_f\}$, $Q_f = \{q_f\}$, and $\Delta =$
>
> \begin{align}
> a &\to q(a)\\
> g(q(x)) &\to q(g(x))\\
> g(q(x)) &\to q_g(g(x))\\
> g(q_g(x)) &\to q_f(g(x))\\
> f(q(x),q(y)) &\to q(f(x,y))
> \end{align}

Another similar example is this:

> \begin{align}
> a &\to q(a)\\
> g(q_a(x)) &\to q_g(g(x))\\
> g(q_g(x)) &\to q_g(g(x))\\
> f(q_g(x),q_g(y)) &\to q_f (f(x,y))
> \end{align}

The questions I have are:

1. How the states were chosen. Wondering how you are supposed to decide how many to pick.
2. I noticed $g(q_g(x)) \to q_g(g(x))$ moves outward and stays with $q_g$. Wondering if you are allowed to move "backwards" with states, or between states arbitrarily at different nesting levels. Sometimes the state $q$ moves outwards, other times it moves inward.
3. If the rules are applied (or defined) in any particular order.

Comment: "Normally in a regular automaton for example, you define a grammar and that gets automatically converted to an automaton" I'm not sure what you're talking about. An automaton is a perfectly good, stand-alone mathematical object. What are you proposing does this "automatic conversion"? Some piece of software? Automata exist independently of htat.

Comment: Sorry, I thought grammars were to be converted into automata by software, I haven't used automata directly before.

Comment: That's certainly a common use case.